# SSAS Tabular Time Intelligence

Tags: ssas, dax, tabular, ssas-tabular

I am trying to create dynamic Time Intelligence in SSAS Tabular similar to traditional OLAP Time Intel.

Additionally, I need Time Intelligence that can handle two sets of date hierarchies.  For example, a Transmission Date and an Activity Date.

For example, I am trying to create a simple year-to-date sum of gross sales given that the user has selected two filters in an Excel pivot table.  We are talking about all dates of transmission but only from the point of view of a single activity date.  That is, I want to view 2016 total sales as if it were today, but also as if it were last month (i.e. as of a month ago, what did sales look like?).

An additional caveat is that I need two special calendars: a radio broadcast calendar for the transmission period and a traditional gregorian for the activity period.

I have started here:

```
YTD :=
IF (HASONEVALUE ( Dates[Years-Bcast] ),
  CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Sales[Sales Amount] ),
      FILTER (
        ALL( Dates ),Dates[Years-Bcast] = VALUES ( Dates[Years-Bcast] )
                       && Dates[DatesKey] <= MAX ( Dates[DatesKey] )
     )
   ),
BLANK ()
)
```

The problem I assume is my filter; I really want the last FILTER clause to be:

```
&& Dates[ActivityDateKey] <= MAX ( Dates[DatesKey] )
```

The activity date would be a user-defined report filter. It seems I need 2 filters.  The first filter is filtering out only the applicable transmission dates I need, so then my activity date filter is pointless.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this might be what you're looking for..

KEEPFILTERS - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh758426.aspx